# Static files not being served on Bottle in Python

Tags: javascript, python, css, bottle

I'm trying to set an application up which takes a template HTML file and modifies it live. It's working to an extent, but the images and CSS on the pages aren't being served, and there are HTTP 500 errors on the console when they are requested.

This is my directory structure

```
Server/
    assets/
        css/
            img/
            jquery.css
            kickstart.css
            zellner.css
        js/
            jquery.min.js
            kickstart.js
        style.css
        tb_404.png
        tbrun1.png
        tbservers.png
    403.html
    404.html
    500.html
    appid
    index.html
    maintenance.html
    server.log
    server.py
```

This is how I set up the routing in server.py:

```
@error(403)
def error403(error):
    return static_file("403.html")

@error(404)
def error404(error):
    return static_file("404.html")

@error(500)
def error500(error):
    return static_file("500.html")

@route('assets/<filepath:path>')
def server_static(filepath):
    return static_file(filepath, root='assets')
```

And in my html files, the files are linked like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery.snippet.min.js"></script>
```

Could it be due to the statics being in subdirectories in assets/? Or have I completely misunderstood how to use static_file?

This is the type of error I get on the Python console:

```
[07/May/2012 10:51:05] "GET /tempus/23 HTTP/1.1" 200 4501 <h1>Critical error while processing request: /tempus/assets/js/jquery.snippet.min.js</h1>
```

I don't understand why it's routing to /tempus/assets/ ...

Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

I also had problems with serving static files. Here is my solution:

```
@route('/static/:filename#.*#')
def send_static(filename):
    return static_file(filename, root='./static/')
```

and when you want to access a static file eg. a template file:

```
@route('/')
def index():
    output = template('static/index.tpl')
    return output
```

Comment: Saved me! Correct answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You have to put the complete path to the file in root= and it depends on where the program is running.
Take a look at this: http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html?highlight=static_file#tutorial-static-files

Comment: This. Paths are relative to the working directory, not the python module which is the server. `root=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'static')` does the trick for me

Answer (score 1):

Your @route decorator is incorrect for serve_static.

It should read @route('/assets/')